# Skip row count based on the value of one column using ROW_NUMBER

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using ROW_NUMBER() to organize the number of times a certain Code is used for each VisitID.  Below is a modified piece of the query for an example.

```
 SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VisitID ORDER BY EventActualDateTime) AS 'RowNum'
    ,VisitID
    ,EventActualDateTime
    ,Code
    ,LocationID
FROM
    AdmVisitEvents
WHERE
    VisitID = '6012227281'
     and Code IN ('ENADMIN','TFRADMIN')
```

[image]

**I am trying to figure out a way to eliminate a ROW if the LocationID is the same as the previous row.**

So my result set should look like:

[image]

This could occur earlier in the row count too.  For instance if the first TFRADMIN Code had the same LocationID as the ENADMIN* Code I would need to skip that row as well. (*The Codes 'ENADMIN' or 'OBSVTOIN' will always be ROW 1, and ROW 2 on will always be a 'TFRADMIN' Code).

So another example would be:

[image]

If this was my result it should only show:

[image]

Comment: Which version of SQL-Server are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is **untested** in the absence of usable sample data (an image isn't usable, as the only way that the volunteers can use it is my transcribing it), however, `LAG` should help you achieve this:

```
WITH CTE AS
    (SELECT VisitID,
            EventActualDateTime,
            Code,
            LocationID,
            LAG(LocationID) OVER (PARTITION BY VisitID ORDER BY EventActualDateTime) AS PreviousLocationID
     FROM AdmVisitEvents
     WHERE VisitID = '6012227281'
       AND Code IN ('ENADMIN', 'TFRADMIN'))
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VisitID ORDER BY EventActualDateTime) AS RowNum,
       VisitID,
       EventActualDateTime,
       Code,
       LocationID
FROM CTE
WHERE LocationID != PreviousLocationID OR PreviousLocationID IS NULL;
```

Note that the `PARTITION BY` clauses aren't really needed in these queries, due to your `WHERE` (`VisitID = '6012227281'`). As `VisitID` can only have one scalar value, the `PARTITION BY` will never generate values for another "set".

Comment: The `VisitID` was only specified for the example, it will be removed in the full query. So i do need the `partition by` ultimately I just forgot to remove it here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` with `ties` clause  :

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES VisitID, EventActualDateTime, Code, LocationID
FROM AdmVisitEvents
WHERE VisitID = '6012227281' AND 
      Code IN ('ENADMIN','TFRADMIN')
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VisitID, Code, LocationID  ORDER BY EventActualDateTime);
```